# All posible states of the system

Tags: r, probability

I have a data frame with different units and probabilities on availability of these units.Now I want to make a new data frame with all the possible states and the probabilities of these states.

```
gen<-c("A","B","C")
prob<-c("0.95","0.82","0.78")
mw<-c("10","20","50")
df<-data.frame(gen,prob,mw)
 gen prob mw
1   A 0.95 10
2   B 0.82 20
3   C 0.78 50
```

So all the possible states are (A,B,C),(B,C),(A,C),(C),(A,B),(B),(A),(NONE). How can I calculate that and make a new data frame with the probabilities for every state.

Comment: what does `mw` mean ? And what is the relationship between `A`, `B` and `C` ? Independent ?

Comment: A,B and C are independent. MW is the unit output power

Comment: Can you show what you want to achive on some state(state, prob, mw) ?and how you calculate this one row?

Comment: So for the state (A, B,C) the probabilities are (0.95*0.82*0.78= 0.60762) and the mw is (10+20+50=80) so for this state the mw is above 55

Comment: Will there only ever be 3 units or could there be more (e.g. D,E, F etc.) which you would also need to combine to achieve a new state?

Comment: There will be more than 3 units! This is just an example.With 3 units I have 8 possible states

Answer (score 0):

```
trials <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(gen)))
for(i in 1:length(gen)){
  trials.tmp <- t(combn(gen,i))
  trials <- rbind(trials,cbind(trials.tmp,
  matrix(nrow=nrow(trials.tmp),   ncol=length(gen)-i ) ))
  }
   trials
```

Should be something like that?

Comment: Yes this is the function I was looking for. How can I compute the probabilities now